# SFTP File Uploads hangs after uploading some files

Tags: c#

I am uploading 16 files at a time . After uploading 15 files it hangs for indefinite period of time without giving any error.
I even tried initializing the connection after each upload that also not working.
I am 
    using Renci.SshNet

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open))
  {
      sftpclient.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
      sftpclient.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(fi.FullName));                       
   }
```

I even tried initializing the connection after each file upload. That too did not worked

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, so we cant help you, its something wrong with the ftpClient, or the end ftp server, or it may even be something wrong with the HDD, but i doubt it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I figured out that the low disk space was causing the problem. Once the disk space was cleared , everything worked like charm.